# Place thumbnail images side by side

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image-gallery

I am trying to achieve this https://www.sitepoint.com/using-modern-css-to-build-a-responsive-image-grid/ scenario here http://www.romero-fliesen.de/test-portfolio/#cbp=http://www.romero-fliesen.de/cubeportfolio/cube-post-1/ by using

```
.cbp-slider-wrap { 
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 4px;
  float: left;
}
.cbp-slider-item, .cbp-slider-wrap {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 4px;
  float: left;
}
```

but i ended up getting the thumbnails smaller in sizes. Any useful tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly you need to set the [flex-wrap property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap).

```
.cbp-slider-wrap {
   display: flex;  //Set images side by side.
   flex-wrap: wrap; //Allows images to wrap into multiple lines avoiding them to shrinking. Number of image per line and their size can be controlled with 'max-width' (below)
}  

.cbp-slider-item {
   margin: 8px;
   max-width: 30%; //In this specific case, 22% will fit 4 images per line whereas 47% 2 images per line. 
}
```

How it looks with:

```
max-width: 30%
```

[image]

```
max-width: 22%
```

[image]

```
max-width: 47%
```

[image]